# Can someone tell me why this code wont work?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, ive been having some problems with the command im trying to do, well, not some trouble, a lot of trouble, ive been trying for 8 hours now and it just doesn't work...

what im trying to do is a suggest command, basically what is does is someone prompts the command using $suggest (their suggestion here), then after sending that to a .txt file it would return back to the command send in the channel and react with a check mark, but no matter what code I use, either it reacts and doesn't send the info the .txt document, doesn't react or send info to the .txt doc or just doesn't react and send the info to the .txt doc
And as I said before ive been trying for HOURS and I still cannot get it to work...

Here is the code that im using:

```
@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, *, value):
    file = open("suggest.txt", "a")
    file.write(f"User {ctx.author.mention} said: {value}\n")
    file.close
    await reaction.message.add_reaction("✅")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't call `close()` at all (missing parentheses), so it's likely that the data doesn't get flushed into the file due to buffering.

Better to use `with`, though:

```
@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, *, value):
    with open("suggest.txt", "a") as f:
        print(f"User {ctx.author.mention} said: {value}", file=f)
    await reaction.message.add_reaction("✅")
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly close needs parentheses after it, and I never used reaction.message.add_reaction, just message.add_reaction("the reaction").
All of this changed and it should work.

```
@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, *, value):
    file = open("suggest.txt", "a")
    file.write(f"User {ctx.author.mention} said: {value}\n")
    file.close()
    await message.add_reaction("✅")
```

Comment: This should be `ctx.message` instead of `message`, as otherwise `message` isn't defined

Answer (score 0):

I cant believe it, all this time it was because I didnt not (ctx) before message.add_reaction

But thanks for your help!